# Having trouble understanding output of line of code -

Tags: c, return, printf, expression

I don't understand the use of `return 0*` statement??

Tried looking for answers on Google

```
return 0*printf("%d",a[i]);
```

I don't understand the outcome.

Comment: It does not make sense. It is just a bad code.:)

Comment: you are multiplying return value of printf by zero. what do you expect.?

Comment: It's the same as `return 0`

Comment: @Ayxan no, it's not the same.

Comment: Where did you find the code? Provide some context.

Comment: @Ayxan It prints and then returns so they are not same.

Comment: @GreenTree well, yes it prints the value then returns 0

Comment: @dhruv sangwan Instead of return 0*printf("%d",a[i]); there could be written return printf("%d",a[i]), 0; that looks more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me then this

```
return 0*printf("%d",a[i]);
```

just a bad programming style.

At least it would be better to write instead

```
return ( printf("%d",a[i]), 0 );
```

not saying about

```
printf("%d",a[i]);
return 0;
```

Maybe this statement is found in a recursive function.

As for your question

> Having trouble understanding output of line of code -

then this line outputs the value of the `i-th` element of the integral array `a` and exits the corresponding function.

Comment: reader, please use printf call + return statement in production.

Comment: `return ( printf("%d",a[i]), 0 );` Why? Please don't do that. It doesn't improve anything and harms readability. Use two separate statements to print then return

Comment: @Ayxan It seems the original statement is taken from some program that is intentially written with minimal statements. So I showed how to make it more clear that no questions arise.:)

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR** - it's writing the value of `a[i]` to standard output, multiplying the number of characters written by `0`, and returning the result...which is always `0`.

I'd like to see the rest of the code for context - based on this single line of code it doesn't make sense, but maybe in context it would look a little less nonsensical.

`printf` returns the number of characters (bytes) written to the output stream, so this is writing the value of `a[i]` to standard output, multiplying the number of characters written by `0`, and returning the result ... *which is always `0`*, so again, this line in isolation doesn't make a ton of sense.

I'm hard-pressed to think of a use case where this would be logical, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.  Perhaps the author wants to make sure the value of `a[i]` gets displayed even in the event of an error, but why not just do

```
if ( error_occurred )
{
  printf( "%d", a[i] );
  return 0;
}
```

in that case?

It could be the author intends the print statement to be executed concurrent with the return, in which case they don't understand how C works.  It could be the author confuses terse code with fast code, in which case they still don't understand how C works.

Or maybe the author is being tricky for tricky's sake.